# Which is dictionary definition of "Schedule" used in this website?

Tags: meaning-in-context

http://cannabisexpress.co.nz/blog/post/what-does-a-schedule-i-drug-mean

Which is dictionary definition(below link) of "Schedule" used in the website above link?
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/schedule

---

Edit:

> Drug scheduling is a way of ranking illegal drugs based on their medical value and potential for abuse. Countries use scheduling systems to determine how to enforce laws against certain substances. The scheduling system usually ranks in numbers, and different countries have their own classifications for each drug, albeit mostly similar to each other and the United Nations (UN).
>
> The UN classifies drugs from Schedule I through IV, using the same concept of medical value and potential for abuse, albeit worded differently.

Comment: Can you please include a quotation from that link, so that we don't have to go to another site to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here "schedule" means *a formal list* (Cambridge)

> a schedule of prices/rates

If you read through the article, you will find this explanation:

> Schedule I illegal drugs are generally the harder drugs. Under the United Nations classification system, Schedule I drugs pose the most serious risk to public health and have a very limited, if any, therapeutic usefulness.
>
> The same holds true in the United States but the wording is a bit different. There, as previously stated, Schedule I drugs have the highest potential for abuse and no medical value at all.

This means that *"Schedule"* is a formal list (a classification system) that categorizes drugs by (1) the risk they pose to public health and (2) their medical value. The roman numbers (Schedule I, II, III, IV, etc.) are just the different categories or classes of drugs.

Answer (score 0):

Related to that context, a good definition for a `schedule` (noun) I found,  was:

```
An appendix to a formal document or statute, especially as a list, table, or inventory
```

This is a good explanation of the difference between schedules and other types of appendices in law terms:
https://www.michalsons.com/blog/of-appendices-annexures-and-schedules/11774